# No se encuentra Slim\Container en Slim4

Tags: php, slim, phpstorm

Tengo el siguiente código. Estoy usando **Slim 4.2**

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php';
//Cuando ocurra un error en nuestra api
$c = new \Slim\Container(); //Create Your container

//Override the default Not Found Handler before creating App
$c['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) {
return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {
    return $response->withStatus(404)
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        ->write('Page not found');
};
 };

//Create Slim
$app = new \Slim\App($c);

$app->get("/",function (Request $request, Response $response)
{
$response->getBody()->write("El api esta corriendo");
return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Slim\Container' not found.

Leí la documentación y usa exactamente la misma forma de llamar al container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `Slim v4.x` no existe una clase `Slim\Container` (*pero si la había en la [`v3`](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/di.html)*).

### Solución

Usar [`Dependency Container`](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/di.html) con [`PHP-DI`](http://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html)

- Instalación usando `composer`

  ```
  composer require php-di/php-di
  ```
- Ejemplo de uso:

  ```
  use DI\Container;

  // Create Container using PHP-DI
  $container = new Container();
  ```